Why does element a not take the text color from its predecessors
This is the code
<nav class="navbar">
        <h1 class="logo">ADVENTURE</h1>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tour</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="ctn"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
    </nav>

I tried to make the text color of navbar be #fff(white color)
the h1 changed but the a element doesn't affected

Try this .navbar > *{ color: #fff;}

Use your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied, you’ll notice that the browser is colouring the a element text.

you were not told why yet.. because despite color being inherited, that's true as long as there's not value set for that element. Since <a> elements have a default value set by the browser, such color will be overridden only if the elements is directly addressed. <h1> on the other hand has no default value for color so it does inherit from ancestor. (I see now that the answer actually said that.. ignore my comment then)

Browsers apply their own default styling to links ('a' elements). These defaults usually include a blue color for unvisited links and purple for visited ones.  To override this, you'll need a rule that targets the 'a' element explicitly.


.navbar a { /* Targets links within the navbar */
    color: #fff; 
}



